# suppose that f(z) is holomorphic in the unit disc centered at origin and for all positive $n\geq2$ satisfies $f'(\frac{1}{n})+f(\frac{1}{n})=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is holomorphic in the unit disc centered at origin and for all positive $n\geq2$  satisfies $f'(\frac{1}{n})+f(\frac{1}{n})=0$.

Find $f(\frac{i}{2})$

How we going to proceed this problem i am not getting any idea

Comment: Let $g(z) = f'(z)+f(z)$. Note it is holomorphic around $z= 0$, and $\forall n \ge 2, g(1/n) = 0$ means that $z=0$ [is a non-isolated zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), i.e. $g(z)$ is ... ?

Answer (score 1):

For any $c\in \Bbb C$, the function $f(z)=ce^{-z}$ fulfills that requirement, and depending on the $c$, $f(i/2)$ could be anything.